# Bash script to filter out files based on size

Tags: bash, shell, logging, filtering, uniq

I have a lot of log files which are all unique file names, however based on the size, many are exactly the same content (bot generated attacks).

I need to filter out duplicate file sizes or include only unique file sizes. 
95% are not unique and I can see the file sizes, so could manually choose sizes to filter out.

I have worked out

`find . -size 48c | xargs ls -lSr -h`

Will give me only logs of 48 bytes and could continue with this method to create a long string of included files

`uniq` does not support file size, as far as I can tell

`find` does have a `not` option, this may be where I should be looking?

How can I efficiently filter out the known duplicates?

Or is there a different method to filter and display logs based on unique size only.

Comment: Do you know the file size, or do you just want do find files with identical size and exclude them?

Comment: Testing, the `!` operator works as well as `not` for `find` and manual exclusion of files is possible.

Comment: Benjamin W, I would like to do the latter, though I can manually ID file sizes, there are 48 thousand logs, so "find files with identical size and exclude" is my goal

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One solution is:

```
find . -type f -ls | awk '!x[$7]++ {print $11}'
```

$7 is the filesize column; $11 is the pathname.
Since you are using `find` I assume there are subdirectories, which you don't want to list.

The `awk` part prints the path of the first file with a given size (only).
HTH

Comment: But the OP wants all the files for which no other file with the same size exists.

Comment: This appears to be quite close, I added this to the end `| xargs ls -lSr -h` to view it with file sizes, and there are no subdirectories in this location.

Comment: Minimal example for which this doesn't work: two files with identical size; it will return one, but it should return none.

Answer (score 0):

You nearly had it, does going with this provide a solution:

```
find . -size 48c | xargs
```